# Import TLS certificate tu use LDAPS on client machine

Tags: ldap, centos5, openldap, tls

I installed OpenLDAP server and I configurated TLS on the same machine (CentosOS 5) . Now I would to use LDAPS from an other machine: How can I import the generated certificate?

I used this to [enable LDAPS](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/185.html)

Comment: Import it where? your operating system? a piece of software that has it's own truststore?

Comment: import the certificate on a different macchian with CentosOS. I want to use ldapS on Liferay (which runs on Tomcat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved:

I followed [this](http://www.whitneytechnologies.com/?p=4).

I generated a certificate (root.crt) and I added this into my keystore (where runs tomcat with ldap client). I used keytool to import the certificate file.